Does not using log based broker break event driven architecture
If I am using a queue (SQS or RabbitMQ) to communicate events between micro-services then does it not conform to the requirements of event driven architecture? as, I am not using a durable (log based) messaging it will not be possible to reconstruct the state of the system in case of a failure.
What are the best practices to follow while designing event-driven architecture.

No disrespect but 'What are the best practices to follow while designing event-driven architecture' (specifically) is a big question - you should be able to find existing guidance online.

Just because something isn't durable doesn't mean it's not event based.

I think there is a confusion between event driven architecture and event sourcing.

Event Sourcing: Stores the history of events rather than the actual state
Event Driven Architecture: Uses events to trigger some action in one/multiple decoupled service(s)

EDA is all about loose coupling. The event producer don't know (care about) the event consumer(s). It embraces decoupling between services.
ES is a way to capture and store sequence of state-changing. Either for replayability or audit purposes or whatsoever.

EDA's services can use ES to store state but does not have to.
So, SQS/RabbitMQ can be used for service-to-service communication in an EDA without any problem.
